# preg_replace() not finding ending delimiter?

Tags: php, mysql, preg-replace, preg-match

I use `preg_replace()` alot but I'm not a genius at it.

If I start up a function and deliberately key in all the smilies that I want to use e.g.

```
<?php
function parse_emotes($body){
    $body = preg_replace("#\:p#i", "<img src='images/emotes/tongue.png' alt=':p' title=':p' />", $body);
    //they continue like i said
    return $body;
}
?>
```

but today I tried to change it up and use mysql to let me just insert and delete them as I please without playing in my code, but when I tried it, it only throws

> Warning:  preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: No ending delimiter
>   '#' found in PATH/TO/FILE.php on line 226

Here is the code I used the first time:

```
<?php
function parse_emotes($body){
    while($row = $db->Query("SELECT * FROM emotes", 3)) {

        return $body = preg_replace($row['regex'], "<img src='images/emotes/" . $row['src'] . "' alt='" . $row['alt'] . "' title='" . $row['alt'] . "' />", $body);
    }
}
?>
```

That didn't work, and yes the regex row included the delimiters so it would output `#\:p#`

I got the same error as stated before and then I tried to take the `#`s out of the data in MySQL and just changed `preg_replace` as follows

```
preg_replace('#' . $row['regex'] . '#i', .......)
```

and it still does not like it? I have also tried assigning:

```
$regex = $row['regex'];
preg_replace("#$regex#i");
```

Guess what? Still a no. Any help with where to go with this is very appreciated.

Comment: It's because you can use # to start and end a regular expression. You need do something like "/".$row['regex']."/"

Comment: sorry i should have stated that # is to begin and end my expressions

Comment: then you need to escape it, if you are going to also use the pound sign. "#\".$row['regex']."#", maybe use || or {} instead. Also i am assuming $row['regex'] is just #. Do you really need to use preg_replace, can you use str_replace?

Comment: thanks but it just changes which delimiter is not found, and all mysql row has the data already escaped. adding "#\".$row['regex']."#" escapes out of the quote and if i where to double escape ("#\\".$row) that just escapes $row

Comment: Can you `var_dump($row['regex']);` and tell us what you get?

Comment: Are you sure `$row` contains `#\:p#`?

Comment: @SamirTalwar string '\:p' (length=3)

Comment: @Shef it used to but not any more i removed it because of the error...

Comment: You're aware that your code will only ever try and replace the first emote returned from the database, due to the `return` within the loop?

Comment: this is just an example @salathe this is inside a giant class that i was just trying to keep small and simple

Comment: @devxdev what exactly are you getting from $row['regex'], it should work with no problems.

Comment: @devxdev please don't give broken examples.

Comment: @salathe sorry bro :/ first time using this place,

Matt var_dump told me i was getting exactly what i needed from it.. e.g.: \:p which would have looked like this to the php parser: preg_replace("#\:p#i",.....)

Comment: you could try foreach($db->Query("SELECT * FROM emotes", 3) as $row) {

Comment: What is the backslash in front of the colon supposed to mean?

Comment: @DanielBrockman that escapes the colon because you need to escape characters in preg_replace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since people are still downvoting this topic. @salathe was correct in the questions comments (returning in the loop.. Ooops).

but here is the answer:

```
$emotes = $db->select(['regex', 'class'])->from("emotes")->execute();
while ($emote = $db->fassoc($emotes)) {
    $body = preg_replace("#{$emote['regex']}#i", "<i class='sprite-emote {$emote['class']}'></i>", $body);
}
/* ...other parsing... */
return $body;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code from

```
preg_replace('#' . $row['regex'] . '#i', .......)
```

to

```
preg_replace('/' . $row['regex'] . '/i', .......)
```