# preg_replace not working as expected replacing backslashes?

Tags: php, encoding, delimiter, pcre

I was using the delimiters described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619476/preg-replace-not-finding-ending-delimiter#10752151):

Here is shell php I'm using to demonstrate the problem:

[image: php cli]

I'm using a function on a web project that replaces a namespace syntax for a path, eg:

```
\org\project\namespace\access
```

should be converted to:

```
/org/project/namespace/access
```

But I tried many ways, some threw the following warning:

> Warning: preg_replace(): No ending delimiter '/' found in...

Which I don't want to show.

The warning above shows when using this as regex: `/\\/`

**extra:** (please look at the image) why it shows a bad encoded string?

**UPDATE:** why does it not work as [this PHP Live Regex](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/iVn) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to use `"/\\\\/"` instead of `"/\\/"` because `\\` will produce `\` (a single backslash) in a PHP string literal.

   See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php
2. Why are you using regular expressions for such simple case? Stick to [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) or [`strtr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php):

   ```
   echo strtr($str, ['\\' => '/']);
   ```

Comment: Why [in the phpliveregex page](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/iVo) your `/\\\\/` does not work?

Comment: Because that page gets the pattern from the request form. It isn't a string literal in a PHP code.